# Subtitute 3D Object Texture in After Effects

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes, tracking

Imagine a 3D animation of an open book surrounded by a hugely complex scene, with the camera slowly approaching and/or orbiting it in multiple different trajectories made to flow into each other to be later ordered in infinite combinations. The idea is to have a single reusable base render of this for saving render time, and then to composite different textures for the pages on each trajectory combination. The textures are actually footage, not images, so we have some magical moving text. Goal here to accomplish this in the most efficient possible maner, since it needs to be done over and over again in this project, not only once.

**I've thought of a couple of solutions:**

**1. (Blender only)**. Use HDRI of scene to re-render only the book page with different texture, then comp it sustituting original's color passes. This bypasses rendering the whole scene dozens of times. Problem: will have to manually load textures of each book's page and manually position camera's NLA strips for each trajectory, or learn Python...

**2. (Blender and AE)**. Use objects attached to vertices on the book's pages to generate motion tracking data, and then export to AE for warping and comping. Would need a way to *directly convert these object's positions into trackers*, instead of relying on motion tracking from the rendered video. Is this possible?

**3. (After Effects only)**. Any of several tracking solutions. Will need to test one by one and see which is the best. This would only need to be done once for each trajectory, then I would simply swap the precomps for each new texture.

- 3.1. Native motion tracking on top of masks produced in Blender. Likely will fail due     to excessive labor or lack of pixel level
  precision.
- 3.2. Use Blender [script](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1ZpQJ2jZ8Q) to transfer camera and book page object. Can texture be     changed natively in AE?
- 3.3. Mocha Pro.
- 3.4. GeoTracker. (Might work importing the mesh of the book page)
- 3.5. Element 3D. (Might work if I manage to transfer camera data from Blender)
- 3.6. Re:Map by Re:Vision. (Possibly the cleanest and fastest solution)

Comment: Even with extensive description I'm a bit lost in your goal ... Do you want to composite texture onto render image? If so try render also UV pass and use Map UV node ... https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/distort/map_uv.html 
...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfq5a.jpg

Comment: @vklidu This is a valid solution and is the Blender implementation of my 3.6 entry on the post using Re:Map. Also bonus for being free. I guess I will do it in AE though, because in Blender the Compositor does not seem to be directly tied to the Video Sequencer which slows work down, though I am new to this and might be wrong, need to study these editors more.

Comment: I'm not sure why to use VSE (Sequencer), but using composite in VSE is simple ... in current file just add a New Scene, switch to VSE Layout and add Scene strip. To se result of of compositor in VSE go to Preview editor's Side panel (N) and change on View tab Scene Strip Display to Rendered ... but if you feel more comfortable with AE ... sure go with what fits you the best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Render* your model ...

[image]

... with enabled **UV pass** ...

[image]

In Compositor use **Map UV** node to map image in render ...

[image]
[image]

To continue in **Sequencer** - add a New Scene (in the same file) and add Scene strip into the Timeline. To see *Compositor* result go to *Preview* editor's *Side* panel (N) and change on *View* tab **Scene Strip Display** to *Rendered*

[image]

Notes:

- In this example I used 3D scene as source for Compositor, if you want to pre-render scene and composite image sequence be sure you save your render **OpenEXR Multilayerd** so the image stores enough color depth info and UV pass for compositing.
- Here I used *Object ID* to mask, but sure Cryptomatte should work better (especially at edges with semitransparent pixels).

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you.